# Create Rule In Form Model

Tags: php, yii

in my Register Form, i want check email already in database:

```
class RegisterForm extends CFormModel
{
        public $firstName;
        public $lastName;
        public $email;

        public function rules()
        {
                return array(
                        array('firstName, lastName, email', 'required'),
                        array('email', 'email'),
                        array('email', 'checkEmail'),
                );
        }

        public function attributeLabels()
        {
                return array();
        }

        public function checkEmail()
        {
                $record = Account::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->email));
                if ($record==null) {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

but not working, how to create my rules for check email? somebody can help me????

Answer (score 1):

Yii validators actually do not return `true` or `false` depending on validation result. Instead they add errors to your model, like this

```
    public function checkEmail()
    {
            $record = Account::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->email));
            if ($record != null) {
                    $this->addError('email', 'Email should be unqiue');
            }
    }
```

Comment: I did like that, when checked, I had the error, but not ajax announcement? why is that?
http://s997.photobucket.com/user/lilk4vin/media/Capture_zpsef4a2d9c.png.html

Comment: Hard to say, provide some code how you perform your ajax validation, your form html etc

Answer (score 0):

Better use CUniqueValidator for this check

```
    public function rules()
    {
            return array(
                    array('firstName, lastName, email', 'required'),
                    array('email', 'email'),
                    array('email', 'unique', 'attributeName' => 'username', 'className' => 'Account'),
            );
    }
```

That should work.